# Android, how to implement an amoled theme over night mode

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-styles

I am making a simple app in kotlin and would like to add an additional option for night mode like this
[example from Material Files app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoqbY.png)
I was thinking of adding a style and applying it programmatically, But I don't know how to do it properly.

Here's my code:

**MainActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    //It is called after super.onCreate because otherwise isNightMode does not return the correct value
    when (ThemeHelper.nightModeChoice(this)) {
        "nightModeFollowSystem" -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
        "nightModeOn" -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        "nightModeOff" -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
    }

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    //If MainActivity is recreated return to SettingsFragment to have a nice animation
    if (intent.extras != null) {
        if (intent.extras!!.getBoolean("TEMA_CAMBIATO")) {
            intent.putExtra("TEMA_CAMBIATO", false)
            navController.navigate(R.id.SettingsFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

**ThemeHelper**,
this part is a bit messy, but it serves to prevent the activity from being recreated unnecessarily.

```
object ThemeHelper {


private fun isNightMode(context: Context): Boolean {
    return context.resources.configuration.uiMode.and(Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
}


fun nightModeChoice(context: Context): String? {
    val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    return prefs.getString("modTema", "nightModeFollowSystem")
}

fun recreate(context: Context, activity: Activity) {
    var flag = true
    if (isNightMode(context) && nightModeChoice(context) == "nightModeOn") {
        Log.d("THEME_HELPER", "Non c'è bisogno di aggiornare")
        flag = false
    }

    if (!isNightMode(context) && nightModeChoice(context) == "nightModeOff") {
        Log.d("THEME_HELPER", "Non c'è bisogno di aggiornare")
        flag = false
    }
    if (flag) {
        val intent = activity.intent
        intent?.putExtra("TEMA_CAMBIATO", true)
        activity.finish()
        activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
        activity.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

}

**SettingsFragment**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext()).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext()).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
}

override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences?, key: String?) {
    if (isAdded) {
        if (key == "modTema") {
            ThemeHelper.recreate(requireContext(), requireActivity())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way btw:

**ThemeHelper**

```
fun applyAmoled(context: Context, view: View){
    val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    if (prefs.getBoolean("modAmoled", false) && isNightMode(context)){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
    }
}
```

**MainActivity after super.onCreate**

```
ThemeHelper.applyAmoled(this, findViewById(R.id.content_main))
```

It's not the best solution but it works, I just need to recreate activity when needed